# How to determine the bounds of this triple integral?

Tags: integration

I have this integral:

$$\iiint \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \,dx \,dy \,dz$$

And I cant really get the boundaries from this shape:
V: $1 \leqslant x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 4$  and $0 \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinates. Please don't try solving it directly...

Answer (score 1):

Set
\begin{align}
  & x=r \cos \theta  \\ 
 & y=r \sin \theta  \\ 
\end{align}
$$dxdy=\left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r ,\theta )} \right|dr\,d\theta={{r}\, dr\,d\theta  }$$
we have
$$\iiint_{V} \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \,dx \,dy \,dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{r}r\frac{z}{r}dzdrd\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Behrouz ! I was thinking about the polar method, but wasn't sure.

Still, after I do the drawing for $\sqrt{1-x^2} <= y <= \sqrt{4-x^2}$ I get two half circles, with radius 1 and 2, but isn't the angle supposed to be from 0 to PI? Because 2pi would be the whole circle.

Also why is the dz integral like $\frac{rz}r$ ? I figured out the boundaries.

Thanks !

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, and would better be posted as a comment. You can comment on other users' posts when you've earned enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks, I know I really wanted to address something regarding the previous answer, which was very helpful, but sadly I didn't have the reputation :( (I'm the OP)

Comment: @Szymon Głębocki Note $x^2+ y^2\le 4\implies r\le 2$ and  $x^2+ y^2\ge 1\implies r\ge 1$ then $1 \le r \le 2$ and $ 0\le  \theta \le 2\pi$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r\implies \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{z}{r}$

Comment: @SzymonGłębocki when changing coordinate systems, you have to multiply the inside of the integral by the Jacobian of the mapping. The Jacobian of the mapping from Cartesian coordinate to cylindrical coordinates turns out to be $r$.